# How to get street address in customer edit form

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-address

Currently, I am in the customer address form

`block`

```
\Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit $block
```

How to use $block and get the street address of the customer address.
I tracked the street address is stored in `customer_address_entity` table in the `street` column.

Answer (score 0):

So looking at the code providing you are within \Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Block/Address/Edit.php

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Block/Address/Edit.php#L263-L267

```
$block->getStreetLine(1);
$block->getStreetLine(2);
$block->getStreetLine(3);
$block->getStreetLine(4);
$block->getStreetLine(5);
```

But if that doesn't work try

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Block/Address/Edit.php#L252

\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Api/Data/AddressInterface.php

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Api/Data/AddressInterface.php#L121

It will be an array

```
$address = $block->getAddress();
var_dump($address->getStreet());
```

Comment: @Dominice var_dump($address->getStreet()); gives me null, and the first is already giving me empty result